# C++ Iterate through 3d array 'no match for operator='

Tags: c++, vector

I already googled it and the common solution seems to be, that the iterator has to be constant. But I still get this error. here is my code:

```
std::vector<std::vector<std::vector<std::string> > >::const_iterator itc;
std::vector<std::vector<std::string> >::const_iterator itb;
std::vector<std::string>::const_iterator ita;
for (ita = metadata.getTestVektor().begin(); ita != metadata.getTestVektor().end(); ++ita)
{
    for (itb = ita->begin(); itb != ita->end(); ++itb)
    {
        for (itc = itb->begin(); itc != itb->end(); ++itc)
        {
        }
    }
}
```

metadata.getTestVektor() returns a 3d vektor:

```
std::vector<std::vector<std::vector<std::string>>> testvektor;
```

Log:

`/home/MetaDataCreator.cpp:20: error: no match for 'operator=' (operand types are 'std::vector<std::basic_string<char> >::const_iterator {aka __gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator<const std::basic_string<char>*, std::vector<std::basic_string<char> > >}' and 'std::vector<std::vector<std::vector<std::basic_string<char> > > >::iterator {aka __gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator<std::vector<std::vector<std::basic_string<char> > >*, std::vector<std::vector<std::vector<std::basic_string<char> > > > >}')
     for (ita = metadata.getTestVektor().begin(); ita != metadata.getTestVektor().end(); ++ita)
                           ^`

The ^ points at the "=" sign

Comment: Does `metadata.getTestVektor()` return the vector by value or by reference? Can you please show us the declaration of `getTestVektor()`?

Comment: Also, *where* do you get the error, on which line?

Comment: I'm a C++ noob so I am not sure. metadata.getTestVektor() returns the attribute testvektor in the metadata class (return testvektor). How the testvektor attribute looks like is in the post

Comment: If `getTestVektor` return the vector by value, then the outer loop will not work. Furthermore, can you please show the *complete* error, including any informational messages from the compiler? It usually contains lots of hints as to what the problem might be. Please copy-paste the build log into your question.

Comment: Lastly, I assume that in the inner loops you mean `++itb` and `++itc`? Please learn how to create a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), seeing complete code (including variable or function declarations) is very helpful in diagnosing problems.

Comment: Your compiler should report the offending line numbers. Please paste the compiler messages as is without any editing.

Comment: For the love of god, use `auto`.

Comment: Also you may want to try `cbegin()` and `cend()` instead of `begin()` and `end()`.

Answer (score 1):

Seems like you have got `ita` and `itc` mixed up, with `ita` having the type of the innermost iterator.

But also consider what Joachim said - if `getTestVektor()` returns by value, you call `begin()` and `end()` on two different vectors. Not good!

Comment: That `begin()` and `end()` are two different vectors are only the *beginning* of the OPs problems, because the vectors will be *temporary* as well and will be destructed before the iterators are used.